# Why does $f: \mathbb{T} \rightarrow \mathbb{C} \in C^k$ imply that $f$ is bounded?

Tags: complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

From a book on Harmonic Analysis:

[image]

**Question:** Why does $f^{(j)}(- \pi) = f^{(j)}(\pi)$ in this context imply that $f$ is bounded?

**EDIT:** Does here the author just mean that the function's domain is bounded? If so, I've mistaken a trivial statement with something deep :)

Comment: I believe he means $f$ is $\mathcal C^k$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$, which means that $f$ is continuous, which by the extreme value theorem means it's bounded (adapting the theorem to $\mathbb C$ by view ing it as a 2d real vector space and $f$ as a pair of function $f_x$ and $f_y$).

Comment: The text says it extends $f$ periodically on $\mathbb R$, imposing that $f(\pi) = f(-\pi)$, $f'(\pi) = f'(-\pi)$, ..., $f^{(k)}(\pi) = f^{(k)}(-\pi)$.  Hence the extension is defined on $\pi$.

Answer (score 1):

**Some hand-wavy reasoning**

The statement $f^{(j)}(\pi)=f^{(j)}(-\pi)$ implies that $\Bbb T$ should be used with the unit circle topology. It might me more common to define $f:S^1\to \Bbb C$. However, $\Bbb T$ with the unit circle topology is compact and $f$ is continuous. So the image of $f$ is compact too, which means closed and bounded.

---

**Still hand-wavy, but different**

The author made $f$ to be defined on $[-\pi,\pi)$ which excludes $\pi$, so the expression $f^{(j)}(\pi)$ seems technically meaningless. But he means to extend $f$ to $[-\pi,\pi]$ in a $C^k$-compatible way. Now $[-\pi,\pi]$ is still compact and $f$ continuous. So the above reasoning still applies.